# How I can response to client requests one by one in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to response to client request one by one.
Consider the following code:

```
let i = 1;
router.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    // Wait for response to previous request from another client (If there is)
    console.log(i)
    setTimeout(function() {
      i++ 
      return res.json(true);
    }, 10000);
});
```

I would like to respond to two consecutive requests as follows:

in 0s: log 1 
And after replying to the previous request 
in 10s: log 2

Answer (score 0):

https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue

This doesn't handle errors in the callback, but you get the idea of the machine.

```
const async = require('async')

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    task.res.json(true)
    callback();
}, 1); // concurrency 1

let i = 1;
router.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    q.push({res}, (err) => console.log(i++)) 
});
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Good work making a minimal example of your problem, btw.